# How can I prevent object(s) from casting shadows on certain object(s)?

Tags: shadows

I'm making a scene with a spaceship on Earth's orbit. I won't have it in the same scale so I need to prevent the spaceship from casting shadow on the Earth.

Ideally, the spaceship would be created from multiple objects. The Earth is composed from multiple spheres (planet, clouds, atmosphere). I also need the spaceship to be able to receieve shadows from another objects, so I can also add an astronaut floating around it.

How can I achieve such conditions? Thanks for replies.

EDIT: I also want the spaceship to cast shadows on itself.

Comment: .. I'm assuming you still want the spaceship to cast shadows on itself?

Comment: What render engine do you use?

Comment: easiest fix would be to put the planet and ship on different layers, render them separately and the recombine them in the compositor/VSE.